# Quantlib : forecastingFixing() vs pastFixing()

Tags: quantlib

Quantlib has 2 methods as below:
virtual Rate forecastFixing(const Date& fixingDate) const = 0;
Rate pastFixing(const Date& fixingDate) const;

Am I right in saying :

1. forecastingFixing() method rely on yield curve constructed to get the
   rate?  and
2. pastFixing() simply reads rate without help of any yield curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct.  `pastFixing` relies on stored fixings, that you can save through the `addFixing` or `addFixings` method of the corresponding index; for instance,

```
Euribor6M index;
index.addFixing(Date(20,October,2010), 0.02);
```

will store a 2% fixing for the 6-months Euribor that will be accessible from all instances of the class.  As you say, `forecastFixing` will forecast the rate on a given curve instead.

Usually, though, you won't be calling either of those directly.  You can call the `fixing` method; it will detect whether or not the date you requested is in the past and it will dispatch to the correct method.